# How to pick the maximum and minimum value across a number of columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to select the maximum and minimum values across certain columns to use those values to plot a graph.

Example:

### A | B | C

### 1 | 2 | 3

### 5 | 6 | 4

### 9 | -2 | -1

I want to take the columns A B C and find the maximum value out of the 3 columns and use that as my maximum point (which would be 9 in column A). Then I would like to take the smallest value out of the 3 columns and use that as my minimum point(in this case it would be -2 in column B).

Comment: `vals = df[['A','B','C']].values; max_point, min_point = vals.max(), vals.min()`?

Comment: Sorry i'm really new to python, could you explain more about this code?

Comment: `vals = df[['A','B','C']].values` turns your dataframe into a numpy array. `vals.max(), vals.min()` do what you are asking for. `a,b = c,d` is so called unpack assignment. You can look them up.

Comment: @QuangHoang your code works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this for the maximum value. `df.loc[df['A'].idxmax()]`